# Getting 500 Server Error with RewriteEngine On

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am trying to do some basic .htaccess file stuff and it will not allow me to use RewriteEngine On. Can anyone help?

Here is the `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine On


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA, L]
```

Comment: Is `mod_rewrite` available? Check your error logs.

Comment: @Jason McCreary how would I do so?

Comment: Try removing the condition with `!-l`.

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos still get the error

Comment: @JasonMcCreary im not sure how would I do so?

Comment: Try `# a2enmod rewrite` to enable mod_rewrite on apache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by changing the `[QSA, L]` to `[QSA,L]` removing the space worked!